# Failing to print characters from file

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read from a file and for some reason sometimes it works and sometimes I get the most bizarre results ever.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *f = fopen("mac_input_off.txt","r");
    char c[2] = "";
    while ( 0 != fread(c,sizeof(char),1,f) )
    {
        c[1] = '\0';
        printf("%s",c);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

In windows, visual studio 2013 it works just fine, but in ubuntu linux, on vmware, for some reason it refuses to read the text and reads only the carriage return at the end of the text(encoded with mac os newlines).

This is the text in the file: `bbb58bc7a385cf89ee2102d5ea8d7cab`.
A possible reason is that the 8th bit in every byte is set to 0 in this text.

Any idea what am I not getting?

EDIT: The funny semi-colon terminating the while loop was removed and yet nothing is fixed... back to the drawing board.

Tried to check if it actually reads things by putting a breakpoint after the 10th line in gdb (my actual knowledge of gdb is meager and I can't seem to get any front-end working) and it does in fact read the characters. It just doesn't want to print them.

Comment: I don't have the means of compiling code.  In windows files have two modes: text and binary.  Linux has one: binary.  I wonder if you're simply getting info you're not expecting.  Try a test because those calls should be working.  (Sorry, I'm using a phone and don't know how to make a back-tic.)  printf("0x%02x ", (int)c[0]);  should show you what you're reading.

Comment: `getc`, `putc`. Ever heard of those?

Comment: @PSkocik Do they behave differently? And yes, oh great and condescending master of knowledge, I did try using them. No cigar.

Comment: `  int c;
  while ( EOF != (c=getc(f)))
    putchar(c);
` seem more straightforward (and should be much more efficient -- IDK why you're zeroing out the same zero in each iteration). Anyway, apart from missing error checking on fopen and a missing feof(f), your example seems fine.

Comment: Considering various control characters may be printing, try `printf(" %x\n",c[0]);` to see what is really coming out.

Comment: "This is the text in the file: `bbb58bc7a385cf89ee2102d5ea8d7cab`" is confusing.  Is `bbb58b...` the _text_ or the hexadecimal dump  of the file?

Comment: @AndrewFalanga: you may be able to make a back-tick by finding the apostrophe key and then holding it — to reveal a collection of accents including the back-tick.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the suggestion.  I wasn't able to find a means by holding that key.  Howevery, by using the *virtual keyboard* instead of the *slide-out keyboard*, I was able to find a set of "keys" which included a back-tic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the line:

```
while ( 0 != fread(c,sizeof(char),1,f) );
```

there is no loop body because the statement is terminated with a semi-colon.

Remove the `;` and the statements enclosed in the following `{`...`}` will be executed as the body of the loop. You should then see the contents of the file displayed.

Comment: Eagle eyes — no, Hawke eyes!  Well done.  I don't think the same code was used on Windows after all.  It was similar, but not identical.

Comment: I literally lol-ed after seeing it. Lesse if it works now that the derps are out.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thanks! Yeah, other than the output being slightly different due to different line terminators, I can't explain why this code would behave any differently in Windows.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. Tried to check if it actually reads things by putting a breakpoint after the 10th line in gdb (my actual knowledge of gdb is meager and I can't seem to get any front-end working) and it does in fact read the characters. It just doesn't want to print them.

Comment: @Sunspawn: your revised code works fine for me in Linux (Fedora).

Comment: @Sunspawn: did you remember to recompile your code after making the change?

Comment: Yes, I did recompile it.